# Systemd long boot

Tags: systemd

I have a Dell Latitude 6440 -intel i5-4310 laptop, 8GB RAM disk - SSD.
System on SD card - Ubuntu Mate 18.04.3 kernel 5.2.8. with encrypted partition / home.

This is what system-analyze looks like:

```
Startup finished in
   8.807s (firmware) + 30.926s (loader)  
 + 3.776s (kernel)   + 32.108s (userspace)  
= 1min 15.618s  

graphical.target reached after 32.101s in userspace
```

What is it responsible for and what is the loader + 30,926s ?
How to speed it up?

```
$systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.  
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.  

graphical.target @14.312s  
└─lightdm.service @12.694s +1.617s  
  └─systemd-user-sessions.service @12.671s +13ms  
    └─network.target @12.670s  
      └─NetworkManager.service @10.163s +2.505s  
        └─dbus.service @9.653s  
          └─basic.target @9.641s  
            └─sockets.target @9.641s  
              └─dbus.socket @9.638s  
                └─sysinit.target @9.623s  
                  └─apparmor.service @9.423s +198ms  
                    └─local-fs.target @9.420s  
                      └─home-groszek-.cache.mount @9.416s +3ms  
                        └─home.mount @9.386s +16ms  
                          └─systemd-fsck@dev-mapper-mmcblk0p8_crypt.service @9.3  
                            └─dev-mapper-mmcblk0p8_crypt.device @9.365s
```

```
$ lsblk
NAME                MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
loop0                 7:0    0  71,7M  1 loop  /snap/software-boutique/31
loop1                 7:1    0    16K  1 loop  /snap/software-boutique/39
loop2                 7:2    0  88,7M  1 loop  /snap/core/7396
loop3                 7:3    0  88,5M  1 loop  /snap/core/7270
loop4                 7:4    0   7,9M  1 loop  /snap/pulsemixer/23
loop5                 7:5    0   7,9M  1 loop  /snap/pulsemixer/250
loop6                 7:6    0  87,3M  1 loop  /snap/ubuntu-mate-welcome/220
loop7                 7:7    0  86,3M  1 loop  /snap/ubuntu-mate-welcome/335
sda                   8:0    0 298,1G  0 disk  
├─sda1                8:1    0  39,2M  0 part  
├─sda2                8:2    0  13,8G  0 part  
├─sda3                8:3    0 226,3G  0 part  /media/OS
└─sda4                8:4    0    58G  0 part  
sr0                  11:0    1  1024M  0 rom   
mmcblk0             179:0    0  59,5G  0 disk  
├─mmcblk0p1         179:1    0   285M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─mmcblk0p2         179:2    0     1K  0 part  
├─mmcblk0p5         179:5    0   6,1G  0 part  /
├─mmcblk0p6         179:6    0  15,9G  0 part  /usr
├─mmcblk0p7         179:7    0   6,1G  0 part  /var
└─mmcblk0p8         259:0    0  31,3G  0 part  
  └─mmcblk0p8_crypt 25If you know how to solve this, please leave your comment, I really appreciate it!3:0    0  31,3G  0 crypt /home
zram0               252:0    0   985M  0 disk  [SWAP]
zram1               252:1    0   985M  0 disk  [SWAP]
zram2               252:2    0   985M  0 disk  [SWAP]
zram3               252:3    0   985M  0 disk  [SWAP]
```

```
$ sudo hdparm -tT /dev/mmcblk0
/dev/mmcblk0:
 Timing cached reads:   13722 MB in  2.00 seconds = 6873.86 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads:  70 MB in  3.08 seconds =  22.74 MB/sec
```

Comment: please run `systemd-analyze critical-chain` and edit you question with his output (fyi sd card can be slow)

Comment: *"8GB RAM disk - SSD"* you mean Intel Rapid Storage? You need special Linux drivers to use it.

Comment: Do you really mean that the system is installed on Secure Digital flash card? SD cards have very wide speed range (cheaper → slower, costly → faster). For example Samsung PRO provide real 90 Mb/s write and read rates. Also SD card reader in the laptop maybe slow. Please add output of `sudo hdparm -tT /dev/mmcblk0` (speed test) and `lsblk` (partitions) to the question.

Comment: sudo hdparm -tT /dev/mmcblk0
[sudo] hasło użytkownika groszek: 

/dev/mmcblk0:
 Timing cached reads:   13722 MB in  2.00 seconds = 6873.86 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads:  70 MB in  3.08 seconds =  22.74 MB/sec

Comment: mmcblk0             179:0    0  59,5G  0 disk  
├─mmcblk0p1         179:1    0   285M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─mmcblk0p2         179:2    0     1K  0 part  
├─mmcblk0p5         179:5    0   6,1G  0 part  /
├─mmcblk0p6         179:6    0  15,9G  0 part  /usr
├─mmcblk0p7         179:7    0   6,1G  0 part  /var
└─mmcblk0p8         259:0    0  31,3G  0 part  
  └─mmcblk0p8_crypt 253:0    0  31,3G  0 crypt /home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benchmark with `hdparm` gives very slow read rate

> ```
> $sudo hdparm -tT /dev/mmcblk0
> ...
> Timing buffered disk reads:  70 MB in  3.08 seconds =  22.74 MB/sec
> ```

So this 22 MB/sec is a bottleneck.
Also take into account that this is sequential read speed, while real speeds with random access may be even slower. Encryption may lower speeds too.
Internal HDDs are currently rated at 150 MB/s, while SSDs - at >500 MB/s.

Consider to use one of this options:

- buy faster SD card with Class 10 and UHS I (or UHS III) rating - for example Samsung PRO or PRO Plus;
- buy fast USB-flash - for example ADATA UE700 or Sandisk Extreme;
- buy 2.5" SATA / mSATA / M.2 SSD (I do not exactly know the internals of your laptop) with ~512 GB capacity and move Ubuntu to it after Windows partitions.

Comment: Thank you very much for help. I'm closing the topic.

Comment: "Closing" here is done by accepting answers ([checkmark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOe6h.png) in the left of my answer) if you satisfied with my ideas from the answer :)